# Regridding NetCDF4 in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with various climate models, but right now I'm working on regridding the latitudes and longitudes of these files from 2.5x2.5 to 0.5x0.5, and I am completely lost. I've been running on the Anaconda package for all of my netCDF4 needs, and I've made good progress, it's just regridding that baffles me completely. I have three main arrays that I'm using:

The first is the data_array, a numpy array that contains the information for precipitation.
The second is the lan_array, a numpy array containing the latitude information.
The third is the lot_array, a numpy array containing the longitude information.
All this data came from the netCDF4 file.

Again, my data is currently in 2.5x2.5. Meaning, the lonxlat is currently 144x72. I use np.meshgrid(lon_array,lat_array) to bring lonxlat to go to 72. My data_array also contains 72 elements, thus matching up perfectly.

This is where I get stuck and I have no idea how to proceed.

My thoughts: I want my 144x72 to convert to 720x360 in order for it to be 0.5x0.5. 
I know one way of creating the lonxlat that I want is by np.arange(-89.75,90.25,0.5) and np.arange(-179.75,181.25,0.5). But I don't know how to match up the data_array to match with that.

Can anyone please offer any assistance? Any help is much appreciated!

Note: I also have ESMF modules available to me.

Comment: Do you need to use Python?  NCL's regridding package is ideal for this: https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/regrid.shtml

Comment: Yes, at least it would be preferred that I do, as my future work for this will still be in Python. I see that NCL's package uses ESMF, which I actually have access to in Python.

Comment: Then CDAT is the Python way to go: http://www2-pcmdi.llnl.gov/cdat/tutorials/advanced_cdat/regridding.html

Comment: I looked into CDAT earlier on and downloaded the cdat-lite version on my Mac. The issue was that the modules (cdms2 and regrid2) both were not loading properly (I believe they were ImageErrors?). I'll go ahead and download the full package and hope for the best!

Comment: Good luck and do give NCL a look someday.  It'll make your life much easier in situations like this and has good instructions to install properly.

Comment: Thank you! In addition to trying to figure CDAT's installation out, I am also trying to install NCL.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option would be nctoolkit (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html). This has a built in method called `to_latlon` that easily achieves what you want. Just do the following for bilinear interpolation (and see the user guide for other methods):

```
import nctoolkit as nc
data = nc.open("infile.nc")
data.to_latlon(lon = [-179.75, 179.75], lat = [-89.75, 89.75], res = [0.5, 0.5])
```